# datetime manipulation: Getting Tomorrow's Date

Tags: r, datetime

I have a date string in the form of "yyyy.mm.dd" and I'd like to make a simple function TomorrowDate() that increments the date by one calendar day.  Something of the form:

```
>TomorrowDate("2013.01.20")
"2013.01.21"
```

Any advice?  Thanks!

Comment: Isn't `as.Date("2013.01.20",format="%Y.%m.%d")+1` easy enough?

Answer (score 3):

The documentation in `?As.Date` has the details on converting from and to character representations, and for Date arithmetic. This class is internally the number of days from 1970-01-01, so you simply add 1 to the date to get the next date. Then, you use `format` to return the date in the character representation you desire.

```
TomorrowDate <- function(x) 
   format(
     as.Date(x, format = "%Y.%m.%d") + 1, 
     format = "%Y.%m.%d"
   )
```

Comment: You vote to close, then answer the question? That seems inconsistent...

Comment: What is the difference between my answer and your comment?

Comment: Pssh, don't use your logic on me. :)

Comment: @BlueMagister nothing, but I don't think that is what Joshua is getting at.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Oops - deleted my comment. For posterity, it was: "Wow, a smiley face from Joshua Ulrich! I'm pretty psyched."

Comment: You should be psyched. I almost never smile. :-| And the difference between my comment and your answer is that my comment has more up-votes. \m/ ^_^ \m/

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:
`format(as.Date("2013.01.20",format="%Y.%m.%d")+1,"%Y.%m.%d")`

If you want a function you can simply do

```
TomorrowDate <- function(x) {
    format(as.Date(x,format="%Y.%m.%d")+1,"%Y.%m.%d")
}

TomorrowDate("2013.01.20")
[1] "2013.01.21"
```